# Why I'm getting "No fixtures found." when I run "python manage.py syncdb" command?

Tags: django

I run this:

```
C:\mysite>python manage.py syncdb
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user
Creating table auth_message
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site

You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superuse
rs defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): yes
Username: balu
E-mail address: vabasu@gmail.com
Password:
Password (again):
Superuser created successfully.
Installing index for auth.Permission model
Installing index for auth.Group_permissions model
Installing index for auth.User_user_permissions model
Installing index for auth.User_groups model
Installing index for auth.Message model
No fixtures found.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to have your fixtures to be installed during syncdb I believe you need to put them into `<app>/fixtures/` directory and call the file `initial_data.<ext>`

Check this also:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#automatically-loading-initial-data-fixtures

Comment: Also, PyYAML must be installed if the fixtures are in YAML format, otherwise the "No fixtures found" message still appears. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats

Comment: You can see what's available by using the `get_public_serializer_formats()` function from `django.core.serializers`.