# Django and PostgreSQL "No Fixtures Found"

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I've been trying to use PostrgeSQL with my Django apps but I get the following error before (right after starting the project when I only have the following files: `__init__.py`, `manage.py`, `settings.pyc`, `urls.pyc`, `__init__.pyc`, `settings.py`, `urls.py`) and after I've added models:

```
python manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
No fixtures found.
```

I'm not even trying to load fixtures. Psycopg2 is installed. This is the database section of my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'myapp_development',                     
        # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'foo',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'password',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',       
        # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                    
        # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328708/why-im-getting-no-fixtures-found-when-i-run-python-manage-py-syncdb-command ... I guess this isn't an error, it's just telling you there are no fixtures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that Django had not found any fixtures. This is a standard message if there are no fixtures.

*Fixture* is a file of the next format (using to create real objects in a database by an existing model):

```
[
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Lennon"
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "Paul",
      "last_name": "McCartney"
    }
  }
]
```

See more for details: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/

Answer (score 2):

Did you set the `FIXTURE_DIRS` setting value in your `settings.py`?

See [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Fixtures) for documentation.

Answer (score 1):

When you run

> manage.py syncdb

django try to load initial data for apps in you project.
By default that data loaded from app-dir\fixtures\initial_data.[xml/yaml/json] files
So when file does not exist you see:

**No fixtures found**

Lean more on django [official page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/):